# Matlab strel function parameter as octagon in opencv cpp

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I had few line of matlab code for applying structuring element with Octagon shape. I want to convert the same code into opencv cpp.

## Matlab Code

```
se1 = strel('octagon',3);
imgNew = imerode(image,se1);
```

## Opencv Cpp Code

I know we can create an structuring element then we have to call erode function , but how to create octagon structuring element in opencv.

```
element = ??
erode(image,dst,element);
```

### How to create Octagon structuring element in opencv ?

Comment: There isn't an equivalent call unless you create the structuring element yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to create Octagon structuring element. plz

Comment: If an ellipse fits your needs, you may use the built-in function `cv::getStructuringElement(int shape, Size ksize, Point anchor=Point(-1,-1))`, where shape can be "MORPH_RECT", "MORPH_ELLIPSE" or "MORPH_CROSS". More info at http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#getstructuringelement

Comment: Do `open strel` in MATLAB, then search for the  `MakeOctagonStrel` function. You can translate that source into OpenCV C++.

Comment: Thanks i will try that

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to compute the vertices of the octagon, and use `fillConvexPoly` to draw the octagon.

`M` must be a non negative multiple of 3 (as in Matlab).

**Code**

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat1b getOctagon(int M)
{
    // M positive and multiple of 3
    CV_Assert((M > 0) && ((M % 3) == 0));

    int k = M / 3;
    int rows = M*2 + 1;
    int cols = M*2 + 1;
    Point c(M, M);

    Mat1b strel(rows, cols, uchar(0));

    // Octagon vertices

    //       0-1
    //      /   \
    //     7     2
    //     |  c  |
    //     6     3
    //      \   /
    //       5-4    


    vector<Point> vertices(8);
    vertices[0].x = c.x - k;
    vertices[0].y = 0;
    vertices[1].x = c.x + k;
    vertices[1].y = 0;

    vertices[2].x = cols-1;
    vertices[2].y = c.y - k;
    vertices[3].x = cols-1;
    vertices[3].y = c.y + k;

    vertices[4].x = c.x + k;
    vertices[4].y = rows-1;
    vertices[5].x = c.x - k;
    vertices[5].y = rows-1;

    vertices[6].x = 0;
    vertices[6].y = c.y + k;
    vertices[7].x = 0;
    vertices[7].y = c.y - k;

    fillConvexPoly(strel, vertices, Scalar(1));

    return strel;

}


int main()
{
    Mat1b kernel = getOctagon(3);

    //morphologyEx(src, dst, MORPH_ERODE, kernel);

    return 0;
}
```

**Result**

M = 3:

[image]

M = 12:

[image]